# Face is is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'o')

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I want to build globe using three js like github. I refered this link https://github.com/janarosmonaliev/github-globe/blob/main/src/index.js. I got an error while compiling and the error is :
./node_modules/three-glow-mesh/dist/index.module.js
Attempted import error: 'Face' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'o').

My code is :

```
 const initGlobe = () => {
  Globe = new threeGlobe()
    .arcsData(travelHistory.flights)
    .arcColor((e) => {
      return e.status ? "#9cff00" : "#ff4000";
    })
    .arcAltitude((e) => e.arcAlt)
    .arcStroke((e) => (e.status ? 0.5 : 0.3))
    .arcDashLength(0.9)
    .arcDashGap(4)
    .arcDashAnimateTime(1000)
    .arcsTransitionDuration(1000)
    .arcDashInitialGap((e) => e.order * 1)
    .hexPolygonsData(countries.features)
    .hexPolygonResolution(3)
    .hexPolygonMargin(0.7)
    .showAtmosphere(false)
    .hexPolygonColor((e) => {
      if (
        [
          "KGZ",
          "KOR",
          "THA",
          "RUS",
          "UZB",
          "IDN",
          "KAZ",
          "MYS",
        ].includes(e.properties.ISO_A3)
      ) {
        return "rgba(255,255,255, 1)";
      } else return "rgba(255,255,255, 0.7)";
    });
  Globe.rotateY(-Math.PI * (5 / 9));
  Globe.rotateZ(-Math.PI / 6);
  const globalMaterial = Globe.globeMaterial();
  globalMaterial.color = new Color(0x3a228a);
  globalMaterial.emissive = new Color(0x220038);
  globalMaterial.emissiveIntensity = 0.1;
  globalMaterial.shininess = 0.7;
  var options = {
    backside: true,
    color: "#3a228a",
    size: 100 * 0.25,
    power: 6,
    coefficient: 0.3,
  };
  try {
    var glowMesh = createGlowMaterial(
      new SphereGeometry(100, 75, 75),
      options
    );
    Globe.add(glowMesh);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(
      "Your threeJS version does not support three-glow-mesh"
    );
  }
  scene.add(Globe);
};
```

Comment: The Face3 class is removed in r126. There already seems to be an open issue on the Github repo of `three-glow-mesh` for the same https://github.com/chrisrzhou/three-glow-mesh/issues/8

Comment: please help me to avoid this erorr. How to do that?

Comment: @Sowmiya did u resolve this error? Pls share the fix, if yes.